# Scala compiler throws "internal" type mismatch error without giving error location

Tags: scala, scala-compiler

I'm compiling a project that has 77 Scala files with scala 2.10.5.

I got 0 warning and 1 weird error message:

```
[ERROR] type mismatch;
 found   : Array[?B]
 required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method booleanArrayOps in object Predef of type (xs: Array[Boolean])scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps[Boolean]
 and method byteArrayOps in object Predef of type (xs: Array[Byte])scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps[Byte]
 are possible conversion functions from Array[?B] to scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
[ERROR] one error found
[INFO] ------------------ ....{this line is irrelevant}
```

The error information doesn't indicate the location of the error, so I think this is a scalac internal error. What should I do to debug it?

Thanks a lot for any help.

UPDATES: I enabled debugging mode and see the full stack trace:

```
Caused by: Compilation failed
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:105)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:48)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.sbt$compiler$AggressiveCompile$$timed(AggressiveCompile.scala:166)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.compileScala$1(AggressiveCompile.scala:98)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:143)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:87)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:39)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:37)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(Incremental.scala:99)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:38)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:37)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:65)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:37)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:27)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile2(AggressiveCompile.scala:157)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile1(AggressiveCompile.scala:71)
        at com.typesafe.zinc.Compiler.compile(Compiler.scala:184)
        at com.typesafe.zinc.Compiler.compile(Compiler.scala:164)
        at sbt_inc.SbtIncrementalCompiler.compile(SbtIncrementalCompiler.java:92)
        at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.incrementalCompile(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:303)
        at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.compile(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:119)
        at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.doExecute(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:99)
        at scala_maven.ScalaMojoSupport.execute(ScalaMojoSupport.java:482)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        ... 21 more
```

Is this helpful in identifying the problem?

Comment: it's not "scalac internal error", it's an error in your code. You need to look at the source to figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: Compiler's message seems pretty straightforward to me - your array needs to be converted to `scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce`, but there are two such implicit conversions available in scope so the compiler cannot resolve which one to use. Can't help further without looking at the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found a solution:

scalac 2.10.5 had a glitch on printing out the line number of the error, which is indeed a syntax error in my code.

When I switched to scalac 2.11.7 the line number is printed out, which makes it easy to fix the problem